# Ruby on Rails validation if one attribute is true then cannot be blank else allow blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a true and false questionnaire. I would like the user to give an explanation if click true.

For example :

```
Do you like pineapple in your pizza?
(0)True  ( )False

If true, please explain:
______________________________
|                            |
|                            |
|                            |
|                            |
------------------------------
```

On my validation, I would like to check if is false allow blank and if it is true to not allow the explanation to be blank.

This is what I tried so far for my model validation:

```
validates_presence_of :is_pinnapple_pizza
validates :pinnapple_pizza_explanation, presence: {if: :is_pinnapple_pizza?}
```

The problem is that if I click false, it returns a "can't be blank" error in the question when answer false.

```
Do you like pineapple in your pizza?
( )True  (0)False

can't be blank

If true, please explain:
______________________________
|                            |
|                            |
|                            |
|                            |
------------------------------
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's something wrong with your code. You should use

```
#use inclusion to validate boolean field, because false.blank? => true
validates :is_pinnaple_pizza, inclusion: { in: [true, false] }
validates :pinnapple_pizza_explanation, presence: true, if: :is_pinnapple_pizza?
```

Comment: the `validates_presence_of :is_pinnapple_pizza` is throwing the validation off for some reason. I get a it cannot be blank bellow the first question when answer no

Comment: for `is_pinnapple_pizza`, the problem is that you're trying to validate the presence of a boolean field. Rails use `#blank?` to check for presence. So if its value is FALSE it will still be evaluated to false. Instead you should validate inclusion. I've modified my answer above for this.

Comment: `allow_blank` for `made_you_aware_explanation`? Don't think it's necessary.

Comment: You’re right. I made a duplicate and I realize what I was doing wrong. I deleted that question when i figure out my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I first thought my text area was giving the error, but I notice that the radio buttons were causing problems when you select false. I added my own custom validation instead and it's working

```
validate :validate_pizza
validates :pinnapple_pizza_explanation, presence: {if: :is_pinnapple_pizza?}
private

def validate_pizza
    if is_pinnapple_pizza.nil?
         errors.add(:is_pinnapple_pizza, "PLEASE SELECT YES OR NO")
    end
end
```